# Custom a shape for the imageView

Tags: android, xml, imageview

How can I leave my imageview in this format, without the image "overflowing" the sides and occupy all space

[here is the shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnKC8.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you arleady have the shape, you can add it as `src` in ImageView, and the image set as background of the same ImageView. Because the image is in front of the background.

Answer (score 0):

Set.. android backgroud the purple image and app:src the middle image in imageview.. Hope it helps